# Drupal 7 form api. Add custom class to element after validation

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-forms, form-api

I looked around and could not find the solution as to how to add a custom class to the form element/elements or the `<form>` tag for that matter. I have a custom form validation function which does some custom validation. `form_set_error` does set an `error` class on the elements but I wanted to add my custom class anywhere within the `form` tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the goal is just to customize the display of your field on error, a cleaner way is to create your own theme_form_element() in your theme and use the function form_get_error($element) to add the class you want if any error is returned on a field.
Using this method you can also display the error message next to the field in error, instead of on top of the form.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, What about when error occurst a custom class on the `<form>` tag itself ??

Comment: You can use the hook theme_form to modify the form display and with the function form_get_errors (notice the s at the end) you can get all errors on this form.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8340175/drupal-7-form-validate-add-class). Turns out you can use `$form_state` to  make alterations to form after submission. I did

```
if($haserror) {
    $form_state['complete form']['#attributes'] = array('class'=>array('contains_error'));
}
```